# Create siblings SSAS

Tags: ssas, parent-child, hierarchy, siblings

If you have a parent-child dimension how can the power users easily create new level in the hierarchy?

In SSAS is the posiblity to enable WriteBack and easy create new child and new sibling.
Can you do this also from excel? I don't want that users to login to SSAS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is called dimension writeback but it is not available via Excel.

see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b462fd74-b2d4-4a42-9d8a-809b1d5965b8/writeback-dimension-not-working-with-excel-2010)

Comment: fwiw - this functionality was deprecated in SQL 2014...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143346.aspx